# Java Spring Boot app with multiple database drivers doesn't run on Linux

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, datasource, java-11

This question is NOT about setting up multiple datasources.

We are migrating from database A (Type: Sybase) to database B (Type: MSSQL) but temporarily need to support both while this migration is ongoing. The tables/schema in these two databases are identical. In a Java 11 spring Boot 2.X application, I want to be flexible in which database to use when deploying the application by implementing all datasource configuration in two distinct profiles. This works fine when running locally (IntelliJ/Windows). Running the maven clean install both inside and outside of IntelliJ works fine.

For unit tests, we use dbunit, with an H2 in memory database. This requires an addtional driver. All unit tests pass successfully locally (IntelliJ or Maven/Windows). When running the unit tests, the application's main configuration is not used and all datasource configuration is 100% dbunit configuration.

So everything looks in order right? Unfortunately, when our Jenkins build server (**Linux!**) runs the dbunit unittest, the `HikariPool` can't properly start for those test that require it because of this rather cryptic error:

```
2020-03-26 17:56:27.366  INFO 15845 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-7 - Starting...
2020-03-26 17:56:27.369  WARN 15845 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization ...
2020-03-26 17:56:27.380 ERROR 15845 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
                Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration':
                                Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
                                                Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]:
                                                                Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
                                                                                Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': 
                                                                                                Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
                                                                                                                Could not initialize class sun.security.provider.NativePRNG
```

In my `pom.xml` file I have three dependencies for these drivers (sybase, mssql and h2). If I remove the sybase OR the mssql dependency (thus only have one driver + the H2 database driver) the database setup is successful and all unit test run/pass in Jenkins.

This class that is supposedly not found *does* exists in the Java 11 JDK's that we use (locally it is one for windows, on Jenkins it is the same jdk but for linux).

Some questions I now have:

- I'm completely lost as to why the datasource requires this class, and only on linux machines.
- This class is an empty shell on windows, but it has an implementation on linux (api [here](https://java-browser.yawk.at/java/11/java.base/sun/security/provider/NativePRNG.java#sun.security.provider.NativePRNG)). What does this class try to do?
- Why can't this class load it properly.
- I also don't get why this problem only occurs when multiple drivers are on the classpath, but it doesn't occur when only one is present.

I found only [one blogpost](https://www.simulevski.at/2018-12-20-Spring-Boot-with-Couchbase-and-Neo4j-An-introduction/) about this topic making the undocumented claim that Spring doesn't support multiple drivers:

> One of the problems with Spring is, that you can’t actually use
>   multiple database drivers in the same package. That’s just a
>   limitation Spring has. But fortunately for us, someone, way smarter
>   than me, figured out how you can do the next best thing: separate
>   repositories with different database drivers.

I think this is false because the application runs fine. I don't quite get why building on Jenkins screws up the unit tests. The solution provided in this blogpost won't work for me because I only have 1 package with 1 logic, I don't need these multiple drivers to access multiple datasources.

Comment: @Xerx593 We intended on having only one artifact and using the spring profile to change the behavior at deploy time (every server knows which environment it is, but jenkins/maven can't predict that in advance)

Comment: Do you get that problem on other Linux machines too? If you build skipping tests, does the application work with sybase and mssql? Do you use Hikari with H2 only or with all drivers?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is unusual and not easily reproducible so I have not a proven solution but some important hint.

First of all a common pitfall: `NoClassDefFoundError` does not happen only when a class is not in the classpath but also in case of an unchecked exception thrown by the static initializer of the class.  This fact is not reported in the Javadoc but can be easily demonstrated with this code:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void callMe() {
        System.out.println("Called");
    }

    static {
        if (true) {
            System.err.println("Going to fail");
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Demo.callMe();
        } catch(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //Log ExceptionInInitializerError and continue
        }
        System.err.println("2nd call");
        Demo.callMe();  //NoClassDefFoundError here
    }

}
```

`NativePRNG` is almost empty in Windows but the [Linux implementation](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/solaris/classes/sun/security/provider/NativePRNG.java) has a lot of code executed at classloading time and this code accesses `/dev/random` and/or `/dev/urandom` so a lot of things can go wrong.  Fortunately it has some logging that [can be activated](https://tersesystems.com/blog/2015/12/17/the-right-way-to-use-securerandom/#debugging) with

```
-Djava.security.debug="provider,engine=SecureRandom"
```

and this could help troubleshooting a lot.

Other option: [this post](http://moi.vonos.net/java/securerandom/) explains that you can change the default secure random implementation.  Maybe the so-called SHA1PRNG implementation works.

The error appears when you have both sybase and mssql driver in classpath, but during unit tests and you say that in tests you are using H2 only.  Note that modern JDBC drivers (v4.0+) are autodiscovered and automatically loaded by the classloader (the old `Class.forName()` trick is no more necessary, see [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html#drivermanager)).  Any JDBC driver has a static initializer that, at least, notifies the DriverManager of its existence but could also access `NativePRNG`.

Now some guessing. In my example above you get `NoClassDefFoundError` on the 2nd access to the class. I guess that the first driver that tries to use that class gets `ExceptionInInitializerError` and silently ignores it (maybe it fallbacks to `Math.random()`), then the 2nd (or the 3rd) driver tries to do the same but gets `NoClassDefFoundError` and fails.  This would be a bug in the driver (it should ignore `NoClassDefFoundError` too).  So, if any other option fails, you could try to use a different version (newer or even older) of those drivers or also a different version of Hikari or a different DB pool.

Comment: Thanks, this cleared up most of the "what is going on here?" questions I had. About the extra debug logging - I would need to be able to turn this option on when our jenkins server is building the app using maven (during the unit test execution of maven). Adding the -Dxxx part to the jenkins job configuration didn't do anything. Where can I add it so it gets picked up?

Comment: I would try to build from command line on that machine or any other Linux machine.  In my (old?) Jenkins `-D` options go in a field named "Goals and options".  I would also check those `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom/` files.  Note that I have also extended my answer with a note about JDBC 4.0+.